# MSBuild does not include embedded resources (nhibernate hbm.xml) in binary

Tags: .net, powershell, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on a .net class library project, that uses .net framework 4.6.2.
This project uses NHibernate and does contains a large amount of hbm.xml files for the mapping between db tables and entites.
The *.hbm.xml files in my project have build action 'Embedded Resource' and look like this in the csproj.files

When I build the project on my local machine in debug or release (vs 2017 (15.8.4) MSBuild 15.7.179) everything is working fine, the embedded resources are included in the binary.

However, when the Buildserver clones the git repository (after a full clear of the project) and compiles the project, the embedded resources are not included.
The Buildserver (we use Teamcity) has also the same .net framework version 4.6.2 and VS 2017 (also same version as my local pc) installed and does also use MSBuild 15.7.179

[12:21:37][Step 2/7] Building solution ....\My***.sln

[12:21:37][Step 2/7] Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.7.179.6572 for .NET Framework

The binary that comes out of this build procces does **NOT** contain any (zero) embedded resources

The strange part is when i run the build commands in powershell, under the same windows account for Teamcity, the compiled binary does contain the Embedded Resource??
We already rebooted and installed the most recent windows updates on the build server.

I use JustDecomplile (Telerik) to investigate the binary.

Does anyone has a clue for this strange behaviour.

Thx.

Comment: How did you know those embedded resources not included into the binary? Any detailed log about it when you build it on your server? If you can build it successfully on the build server with MSBuild command line, it should be work for your Teamcity, if not, this issue should be related to the configuration of the build task for Teamcity, you can also share you build task configuration  in your question. No one can give you an accurate answer, if there is only one sentence that embedded resources are not included in the binary file.

Answer (score 2):

A colleague of mine has found the solution,
instead of '**compile**' it had to be the '**build**' parameter that we passed on to msbuild.
Apparently **compile** does not do anything with embedded resources.

initial:
$msbuild $SolutionFile "/t:restore;compile" "/p:Configuration=$buildConfiguration;Platform=$buildPlatform;

solution:
$msbuild $SolutionFile "/t:restore;build" "/p:Configuration=$buildConfiguration;Platform=$buildPlatform;